# AVD not getting started in Android Studio. IDE internal error occured

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I imported one of my android project and tried to run it in a simulator. A soon i clicked the run button and ADB was about to initialize i saw a red balloon" An Internal error occured". Logs show the following error

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1514)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1478)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:373)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:411)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.initIfNecessary(AvdManagerConnection.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.getAvds(AvdManagerConnection.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker.lambda$refreshAvds$496(DevicePicker.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried alot with the solutions mentioned in other problems but all in vain
Any solution for this please
Attached is image also

Comment: try Gennymotion, it is fast as compared to Android AVDs

Comment: Did you try restarting studio?

Comment: use `android list avd` to list AVDs and `emulator -avd <NAMEOFDEVICE> -netspeed full -netdelay none` to launch it. Let me know if these commands work.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by delete all files in `~/.android/avd` 
but my avd still can't run properly.